The directive \"Dialog.ElicitSlot\" is missing OutputSpeech after building skill from Voiceflow
I was building a Alexa Skill from a no-code service called "Voiceflow", and I had made a couple of utterances from a year ago and recently, I was updating a skill by adding a extra utterance for just a test thing something like this.
What it's supposed to do is I ask the Alexa to use the intent and come out as a response. So when I built it on Voiceflow and tested on the Alexa Developer console, I got a error on the skill, looked into the logs, and found this.
{
  "request": {
    "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
    "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.363c1fd6-a5a0-4181-a55b-69f0a18048ee",
    "timestamp": "2024-07-02T08:32:51Z",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "reason": "ERROR",
    "error": {
      "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
      "message": "The directive \"Dialog.ElicitSlot\" is missing OutputSpeech"
    }
  }
}

Apparently my other uttrances worked, but for this one for some reason was not able to go through. So something is messed up in the Alexa Devloper Console. Is there a way to find the thing inside the utterance? It is also not using Lambda.
